# git: merging a branch that's already been merged by mistake

Tags: git, merge, rebase, branching-and-merging, git-cherry-pick

**Branching strategy and some context**:

My team has a few sub-teams, each working on a separate project with its dedicated branch.
The master branch has the common functionality and houses a major software component (let's call it system P) used by all the projects. We upgrade system P in the master branch every month or so, and projects merge the master branch into each project branch when necessary. As of today, the master branch is on version 99 of system P.

My project branch (let's call it the M branch) has a long divergence from the master. In fact, master has never been merged into the M branch since we created M 5 months ago.

My mission is to update M to 99.

[image: The state of the project]

**The approach**:

I decided to merge incrementally, one by one, starting from 97, resolve conflicts, build, and move on to the next version.

**The problem**:

While trying to merge 97, I got an `"Already up to date."` Upon digging, I discovered that a colleague had inadvertently merged master to his feature branch 3 months ago, which would be merged to M. The bizarre part (and I'm not sure how this happened) is that, even though it's merged, the content of 97 did never show up in the final PR and was never added to either his feature branch or M (and he doesn't remember what happened. I looked in the history, there was never a revert commit). So I'm in a situation where, as far as git is concerned, 97 is merged with M, but the actual content of M is missing.

[image: what happened]

**The question**:

So, how do I merge 97 into M without changing the history when git won't merge? Should I try to remove the faulty merge commit from M and then try to merge master with M?

My sub-team is open to working with me if changing the history is the last resort, but what steps do they need to take in case we have to rebase? Will they be affected if they don't have any local branches?

Answer (score 1):

> So, how do I merge 97 into M without changing the history when git won't merge?

Make a new branch, cherry pick 97 into it, resolve merge conflicts, and merge the new branch.

Comment: Do you mean the commit of 97 in master? What about all the commits between that and when M was first created sometime after 96? There's a whole bunch of commits between the two. Cherry-pick isn't accumulative, right? It will only grab that single commit. Perhaps I could create a patch for a range of commits?

Comment: You could, but I answered _the question you asked_. In my answer, I quote your words back at you so you can be clear about what I am replying to. You cannot merge again into master a commit that has effectively already been merged into master (the problem you are experiencing); but you _can_ merge a cherry-picked version of that commit. Git cherry-pick will let you do this to a series of commits if you are having the same issue with multiple commits; note, too, that there is a special command for doing the same thing, it's called rebase (rebase _is_ cherry-pick, in effect).